# Convert UTF-8 file to ISO-8859-1

Tags: java

### **New question:**

**Source:**

```
C:\\temp\\test.csv
"Русслэнд";"Ελλάς";"Réunion"
```

**Expected result:**

```
C:\\temp\\test.properties
"\u0420\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043b\u044d\u043d\u0434";"\u0395\u03bb\u03bb\u03ac\u03c2";"R\u00e9unio"
```

**Current result:**

```
C:\\temp\\test.properties
"????????", "?????","R궮ion"
```

**Code:**

```
try {

            File file = new File("C:\\temp\\test.csv");

            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

            InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\test.properties");

            OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "ISO-8859-1");

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];

            int x;
            while ((x = r.read(buffer)) == buffer.length) {
                ow.write(buffer);
            }

            ow.write(buffer, 0, x);
            ow.flush();

            ow.close();
            r.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**

### Old question:

**

How to convert a big UTF-8 .csv file to ISO-8859-1 in Java 1.6? I want to read a given file, convert and save it.

```
private byte[] convertToISO(File file, Charset enc) {
    // enc = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    try {

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is, enc);

        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();

        int x = 0;
        while ((x = r.read(buffer)) == buffer.length) {
            w.write(buffer);
        }

        w.write(buffer, 0, x);
        w.flush();

        String res = w.toString();

        r.close();
        return res.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to read file: " + file.getPath());
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The output file is not iso. How can I save my converted data from the file into the file again?

Comment: Just use a class which specifies a charset instead of `StringWriter` then, like `OutputStreamWriter(outStream, "ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: Why do you want to use Java 1.6 for this task when there are perfectly fine tools (recode/unix2dos) available on all major platforms?

Comment: Please post your real code (you're not showing the code that calls `convertToISO` and you're not showing the code that writes to a file).  Also please post what is wrong with your output, including an example. "is not iso" does not mean much, with that little information it's not possible to help you.

Comment: Maybe it will not solve your problem but you should r.read(buf) until it returns -1. See Reader.read(char[]) API

Comment: Please see my edit, I have posted a full code example of what I expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not trying to convert from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1, you're rather trying to escape unicode characters into an ASCII stream. This is different from just recoding.

Here is a function that does just that, it escapes unicode chars on the fly while writing to the output stream:

```
public class OutputEscapingStreamWriter extends OutputStreamWriter {

    public OutputEscapingStreamWriter(OutputStream out, Charset cs) {
        super(out, cs);
    }

    public OutputEscapingStreamWriter(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public OutputEscapingStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String cs) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        super(out, cs);
    }

    public OutputEscapingStreamWriter(OutputStream out, CharsetEncoder cs) {
        super(out, cs);
    }

    private static String HEX_DIGITS = "0123456789abcdef";

    @Override
    public void write(int c) throws IOException {
        if (c < 128) {
            super.write(c);
        }
        else {
            super.write(toHexString(c));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        for (int i = off; i < (off + len); i++) {
            write(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        for (int i = off; i < (off + len); i++) {
            write(cbuf[i]);
        }
    }

    private String toHexString(int c) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\\u");
        sb.append(HEX_DIGITS.charAt((c & 0xF000) >> 12));
        sb.append(HEX_DIGITS.charAt((c & 0x0F00) >> 8));
        sb.append(HEX_DIGITS.charAt((c & 0x00F0) >> 4));
        sb.append(HEX_DIGITS.charAt((c & 0x000F) ));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

To use it on a file, just open a `FileOutputStream` and wrap it with the `OutputEscapingStreamWriter` like this:

```
OutputEscapingStreamWriter out = new OutputEscapingStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));
```

A quick and dirty unit test that demonstrates that it produces the output you expect:

```
@Test
public void testConversion() throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputEscapingStreamWriter wrapper = new OutputEscapingStreamWriter(output);
    wrapper.write("\"Русслэнд\";\"Ελλάς\";\"Réunion\"");
    wrapper.flush();
    wrapper.close();
    String result = output.toString();

    assertEquals("\"\\u0420\\u0443\\u0441\\u0441\\u043b\\u044d\\u043d\\u0434\";\"\\u0395\\u03bb\\u03bb\\u03ac\\u03c2\";\"R\\u00e9union\"", 
            result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks how to iterate this byte array return value?

Comment: I changed the answer based on your new problem description

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are trying to print the results in to console. By default any jdk/JRE will use UTF-8 while printing anything in console.

To use ISO-8859-1 charset, You may either use `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1` in your JVM parameters.

Or, You can configure your IDE as shown below[image]